# File is being used by another process after File.Copy

Tags: c#, iis, file-io

I am trying to manage files in my web application. Sometimes, I must create a file in a folder (with File.Copy):

```
File.Copy(@oldPath, @newPath);
```

And a few seconds later that file may be deleted:

```
if (File.Exists(@newPath)) {
  File.Delete(@newPath);            
}
```

However, I don't know why the new file remains blocked by the server process (IIS, w3wp.exe) after File.Copy. After File.Delete I get the exception:

> "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
>   another process."

According to the Api, File.Copy don't block the file, does it?

I have tried to release the resources but it hasn't worked. How can I resolve this?

**UPDATED:**  Indeed, using Process Explorer the file is blocked by IIS process. I have tried to implement the copy code in order to release manually the resources but the problem still goes on:

```
  public void copy(String oldPath, String newPath)
  {
    FileStream input = null;
    FileStream output = null;
    try
    {
      input = new FileStream(oldPath, FileMode.Open);
      output = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
      int read;
      while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
      {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
      input.Close();
      input.Dispose();
      output.Close();
      output.Dispose();
    }
  }
```

Comment: So what is using the file? Clearly you wouldn't just pointlessly create a file which nothing else uses only to delete it a few seconds later, so something must be using it. What is that something?

Comment: The file comes from another system so, it is changed in it I must replace the old one. I am developing a "mirror" system.

Comment: Perhaps this similar question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937966/

Comment: @Bridge `File.Copy()` will always complete and close the file handle before it returns.

Comment: Are you using threads ?

Comment: @Tan No. File.Copy and File.Delete are executed as a consecuence of different http requests.

Comment: Maybe the virus scanner scans the file, which can cause problems.
 i had a similar problem on a desktop pc and tried a "catch three times then raise" strategy which worked well.

Comment: @Christian Sauer I thought about it but If I reboot the IIS process then File.Delete works properly.

Comment: @jbernal: Maybe there is still a handle on the file somewhere? Do you process the file in any way? Maybe that object hangs still in memory?
Does the blockade last forever, without restarting the IIS?

Comment: @Christian Sauer If there is a process working with file I can't find it. I have killed some processes (antivirus included) but nothing resolved the problem. Only when I kill w3wp.exe process. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you verified that you're not accessing the file in other places, apart from copying and deleting?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Yes, with Process Explorer you can know what processes are using my file but none apart my IIS.

Comment: No, what I meant was, no other piece of code in your web application? Are you somewhere else opening the file for reading, and not closing it, or similar? Are those places (copy/delete) the *only* places in your code that you access that file?

Comment: Correct, It is! I didn't expect but an image rendering in the next lines were causing the blockade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File was being blocked by another process without me being aware of it. Process Explorer was really helpful.

Typical easy issue hard to spot.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find which application opened the file handle.
If Process Explorer cannot find that, use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to trace which process is trying to access the file.

Comment: Thank you for this ... I had this problem and was able to identify issue using ProcExp64

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused by file indexers or anti virus software, which typically scan all new files.

Comment: Of course, it is an option but how many time does it take? I have waited for several minutes but the file continues being blocked.

Comment: You could try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from sysinternals. Using the "Find handle or DLL" feature will show you which processes have an open handle on your file.

Comment: Very useful program. I have used it and indeed the only process who uses the file is w3wp.exe (IIS). I am going to implement the copy function with streams in order to write explicitly the close() or dispose() sentence.